# Informix ERROR: A syntax error has occurred. Error Code: -201

Tags: informix

The only statement in my SQL code is

```
DEFINE p_starttime DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;
```

I get this error from Informix 10.5:
ERROR: A syntax error has occurred.
Error Code: -201

Query =
DEFINE p_starttime DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND

Anybody has a clue why this might be happening? It's such a simple statement.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do.  You can only define variables in the context of a stored procedure.  You need to explain which language or program you are using to access the database.  The CREATE FUNCTION statement might have failed for many different reasons.  (Also, as a matter of interest, there never was a version 10.5 of Informix; the versions went 9.40, 10.00, 11.10, 11.50, 11.70.  Which version of what are you using, on which platform?)

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid SQL, as simple as that. `DEFINE` is not a keyword you can use in a query. It is part of the Stored Procedure Language, or SPL syntax, ie:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo();
    DEFINE p_starttime DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND;
    -- do stuff
    RETURN p_starttime;
END FUNCTION;
```

Comment: This gives an error too:

    ERROR: A syntax error has occurred.
    Error Code: -201

    Query =
    CREATE FUNCTION foo()

Comment: Sorry, that was never meant to be a runnable stored procedure. I didn't have access to an Informix instance when I wrote it. It probably should say `CREATE FUNCTION foo() RETURNING DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND; ...`. The salient point is that DEFINE cannot be used in SQL.